# How can I add class to the specific datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, addclass

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker01">
<input type="text" class="datepicker02">
```

I have 2 input that opens the datepicker.I want to add class to the datepicker which opened in the second input (class="datepicker2"). How can I do this?

http://jsbin.com/cixubuto/1/edit

Comment: You want to add the class "datepicker2" to the currently clicked input right?

Comment: No I want to add class to the datepicker which opened in the second input

Comment: You mean the datepicker widget right?

Comment: Yes I want to add class datepicker widget @j809

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs you can set a beforeShow option:

```
$('.datepicker01').datepicker(
{
  beforeShow: function( input, inst){
    $(inst.dpDiv).addClass('aa');
  }
}
);
```

Comment: Yes I'd like to do exactly that, thank you @HarryFink

Comment: At first it work but then I click on this datepicker and after that I click on another datepicker and that datepicker has this class aswell

Answer (score -2):

Try the below , No need to bother about datepicker , considering it as normal jquery selector only, you can solve this issue  :

```
 $('.datepicker01').datepicker();
 $('.datepicker02').datepicker();
 $('.datepicker02').addClass('ClassName');
```